# Cannot install Maven artifact (mvn install) because jar file is open with JRE running in VS Code

Tags: java, windows, maven, vscode-extensions

Until recently I had no issues copying jars to my local repo using `mvn install`.

Now, when I run mvn install, I get the error:

> Failed to install artifact

This is because the jar file is open with an instance of the JRE running in another instance of VS Code - eg when I try to delete the jar from the local repo, I get the error:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in Java
> Platform SE binary

If I close the other instance of VS Code, the JRE running in that instance is closed and I regain access to the file.

I assume it's a Java extension running the JRE, but I'm not sure which. It's hard to pinpoint because disabling one means having to disable the others.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: That behavior is special to Windows, used [JAR] files can not be overwritten and usually also not deleted. That is the way how Windows file-system works. Linux and MacOS works different and allow to delete or overwrite those files, but retain the original file data unless the process that uses them is exited.